# Dropdown Set tax on product page

Tags: javascript, addtocart, ajax, tax

I'm working on a dropdown where user can select tax.
So I edited addtocart.phtml to put my custom code:

I've added an ajax call but I'm stuck how set product tax from 10% to 22%
Can anyone help me?

```
    <?php if ($_product->getOrigData('tax_class_id') == 2 ):?>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
                <div class="field">
               <label class="label" id="txt">Seleziona l'iva desiderata</label>
                  <select class="select" name="changeiva" id="changeiva" required>
                  <option value="0">Selezionare</option>
                  <option value="1">10%</option>
                  <option value="2">22%</option>
                  </select>
            
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['siv'])) {
ob_clean();           
$iva = $_POST["siv"];
switch ($iva) {
  case "0":
    echo "Non hai selezionato l'IVA!";
    break;
  case "1":
    echo " IVA10%!";
    break;
  case "2":
    echo "IVA22%!";
    break;
}
exit();    
}
?> 
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery' ],
    function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("select[name='changeiva']").on('change', function(){
       var siv = $("#changeiva").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:{siv:siv},
    success: function(result){
         $("#test").html(result);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

EDIT:
Hi @Harun can you please get more deeper? Where I need to put that code? And how I pass to $taxClassId the correct value: 10 or 22?
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the tax value of the product based on the selected option.

Here is the code you need to use in your product class(approximately look like this)

```
$product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

    $taxClassId = ($selectedOption == 1) ? 3 : 4; // set 10% tax or 22% tax based on the selected option

    $product->setTaxClassId($taxClassId);

    $product->save();
```

Comment: Hi @Harun can you please get more deeper? Where I need to put that code? And how I pass to $taxClassId the correct value: 10 or 22? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have already implemented the front-end part of the dropdown and AJAX call successfully. Now, you need to update the tax value of the product based on the selected option.

To update the tax value of the product, you can use the Magento **Catalog\Model\Product** class. First, you need to load the product by its ID. Then, you can set the new tax class ID using the **setTaxClassId()** method and save the product.

```
$product = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$taxClassId = ($selectedOption == 1) ? 3 : 4; // set 10% tax or 22% tax based on the selected option
$product->setTaxClassId($taxClassId);
$product->save();
```

Note that in the above code, $productId is the ID of the product that you want to update, and $selectedOption is the value of the selected option in the dropdown.

You can add this code to the if (isset($_POST['siv'])) block in your PHP code to update the tax class ID of the product based on the selected option. Once you update the tax class ID, the price and tax calculations will be automatically updated on the frontend.

Comment: This code is working! BUT this set TaxClassId permanently to product. I need to set it only untill the checkout.
How I can do it? Really thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the tax class ID only for the current checkout session, you can use the Magento session object to store the selected tax class ID and use it during the checkout process.

Try this code

```
session_start(); // start the session if not already started

if (isset($_POST['siv'])) {
    $taxClassId = ($_POST["siv"] == 1) ? 3 : 4; // set 10% tax or 22% tax based on the selected option
    $_SESSION['selected_tax_class_id'] = $taxClassId; // store the selected tax class ID in the session
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Harun, thanks for your reply. I've tried your code in this way to set the tax at 22% (taxClassID 4):
`session_start();
  $taxClassId == 4;
  $_SESSION['selected_tax_class_id'] = $taxClassId;
exit(); `
But tax still on old ClassID

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
session_start(); // start the session if not already started

if (isset($_POST['siv'])) {
    $taxRate = ($_POST["siv"] == 1) ? 0.1 : 0.22; // set 10% tax rate or 22% tax rate based on the selected option
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $item->setTaxPercent($taxRate * 100); // set the tax rate for the quote item
    }
    
    $quote->collectTotals()->save(); // recalculate totals and save the quote
    $_SESSION['selected_tax_rate'] = $taxRate; // store the selected tax rate in the session
    exit();
}
```

Comment: thanks @Harun, but this isn't work neither. It does't set IVA to 22 (TaxClassId 4).
I've tried to edit your code but without success like here 
` $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $quote = $cart->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $item->getProduct()->setTaxPercent(22.00); 
   $item->getProduct()->setTaxClassId(4);
    $item->save();
    }
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
    $_SESSION['selected_tax_rate'] = $taxRate; 
    exit();`

Comment: Maybe we can make this with an observer event?

Comment: You're right .Make it with that

Answer (score 0):

Use this observer class

```
   <?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddTax implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $post = $this->request->getPostValue();
        if (isset($post['changeiva'])) {
            $taxClassId = ($post['changeiva'] == 1) ? 3 : 4; // set 10% tax or 22% tax based on the selected option

            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $product->setTaxClassId($taxClassId); // set the tax class ID for the product
            $this->productRepository->save($product);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="[vendor]_[module]_addtax" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\AddTax" />
    </event>
</config>
```

change the vendor and Module as you want.

Comment: Hi @Harun. I've used your code and FINALLY IT WORKS, I've made only few changes.
I've got only last problem: I'm not able to pass the value selected from dropdown, seems that request->getPostValue() part doesn't work
Can you help me on that last part? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting the expected value, make sure that the data is being sent as a POST request and that the name attribute of the dropdown field in your form matches the key used in $post.

Else

try this

```
$this->request->getParam('changeiva')
```

instead of this

```
$this->request->getPostValue()
```